# shift functor in triangulated category is auto-equivalence

Tags: triangulated-categories

These days I am stuck with the definition of triangulated categories where the auto-isomorphism is replaced by auto-equivalence. For example, by the axiom TR2, when we have a distinguished triangle $X\rightarrow Y \rightarrow Z \rightarrow TX$, then so is $T^{-1}Z \rightarrow X\rightarrow Y\rightarrow Z$. But the rightmost term should be $TT^{-1}Z$ rather than $Z$ and the morphisms are more complicated than the auto-isomorphism case. So can anyone tell me how to understand this case?

Comment: [This](https://mathoverflow.net/a/91902/101848) might be an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two references that set up the definition, in slightly different ways, in terms of an auto-equivalence rather than an auto-isomorphism are:

*Keller, Bernhard; Vossieck, Dieter*, **Sous les catégories dérivées. (Beneath the derived categories)**, C. R. Acad. Sci., Paris, Sér. I 305, 225-228 (1987). [ZBL0628.18003](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0628.18003).

*May, J.P.*, [**The additivity of traces in triangulated categories**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1006/aima.2001.1995), Adv. Math. 163, No.1, 34-73 (2001). [ZBL1007.18012](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1007.18012).

Briefly, you can replace TR2 with a one-sided axiom stating that a distinguished triangle $X\to Y\to Z\to TX$ implies a distinguished triangle $Y\to Z\to TX\to TY$, and then it follows from this and the other axioms that a distinguished triangle $Y\to Z\to TX\to TY$ implies a distinguished triangle $X\to Y\to Z\to TX$ (this is Lemma 2.4 in May's article).

Comment: What concerns me is whether the theory developed for the auto-isomorphism case is still true for the auto-equivalence case.  Since I'm not familiar with French, I can not read Verdier's doctoral thesis. So if there is any translated version, I am eager to read it.

Comment: @user12580 The paper by Keller and Vossieck gives a construction that, when applied to a triangulated category in the "auto-equivalence" sense, gives an equivalent triangulated category in the strict "auto-isomorphism" sense. That might be all you need to avoid having to worry.

Comment: I assume the construction you refer to from Keller and Vossieck's paper is the first two paragraphs from section 2 (plus first proposition). Regarding this, what is $\displaystyle\varinjlim_{n\geq p,q}\operatorname{Hom}_\mathscr{C}(S^{n-p}X,S^{n-q}Y)$? I mean, what are the arrows in the diagram with respect to we are taking colimit?

Comment: @ElíasGuisadoVillalgordo Since $S$ is a functor, it induces a map $\operatorname{Hom}_\mathscr{C}(S^{n-p}X,S^{n-q}Y)\to\operatorname{Hom}_\mathscr{C}(S^{n+1-p}X,S^{n+1-q}Y)$ for each $n$.

Answer (score 0):

$\def\tr{\mathsf{Tr}}
\def\etr{\mathsf{Etr}}$Here's my personal take on this: Let $T:\mathcal{D}\to\mathcal{D}$ be an autoequivalence. It is true that our definition of triangle requires that the fourth term equals the translation of the first one. Thus, as you rightfully argue, $T^{-1}Z\to X\to Y\to Z$ won't be a triangle in general. Let's make up a new concept then.

> **Definition 1.** Let $\mathcal{D}$ be a category with an autoequivalence $T:\mathcal{D}\to\mathcal{D}$. An *essential triangle* in $(\mathcal{D},T)$ is a tuple $(f,g,h,\varphi)$, where $X\xrightarrow{f}Y\xrightarrow{g}Z\xrightarrow{h}W$ are morphisms in $\mathcal{D}$ and $\varphi$ is an isomorphism $W\xrightarrow{\cong} TX$.

Given an essential triangle $\Delta=(f,g,h,\varphi)$, we denote $U\Delta=(f,g,\varphi\circ h)$, the *triangle induced by the essential triangle $\Delta$*.

A morphism of essential triangles
\begin{gather*}
\Delta=(X\xrightarrow{f}Y\xrightarrow{g}Z\xrightarrow{h}W,\varphi)\\
\downarrow\\
\Delta'=(X'\xrightarrow{f'}Y'\xrightarrow{g'}Z'\xrightarrow{h'}W',\varphi')
\end{gather*}
is a triple $(\alpha:X\to X',\beta:Y\to Y',\gamma:Z\to Z')$ such that $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ defines a morphism of induced triangles $U\Delta\to U\Delta'$. In other words, the following diagram commutes:
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X@>>> Y@>>> Z@>>> W\\
@V{\alpha}VV@V{\beta}VV@V{\gamma}VV@VV{(\varphi')^{-1}\circ T\alpha\circ\varphi}V\\
X'@>>> Y'@>>> Z'@>>> W'
\end{CD}
$$
Denote $\tr(\mathcal{D},T)$ to the category whose objects are triangles in $(\mathcal{D},T)$ and whose morphisms are morphisms of triangles, and $\etr(\mathcal{D},T)$ to the category of essential triangles in $(\mathcal{D},T)$. There is an obvious functor
$$
\tag{1}\label{indt}
U:\etr(\mathcal{D},T)\to\tr(\mathcal{D},T).
$$
The functor $U$ is surjective on objects and is fully faithful. In other words, working with triangles amounts to working with essential triangles. An explicit quasi-inverse $F:\tr(\mathcal{D},T)\to\etr(\mathcal{D},T)$ of $U$ sends a triangle $t=(X\xrightarrow{f}Y\xrightarrow{g}Z\xrightarrow{h}TX)$ to the essential triangle $Ft=(f,g,h,1_{TX})$.

> **Definition 2.** Let $(\mathcal{D},T)$ be a pretriangulated category (here $T$ is an autoequivalence). An essential triangle $\Delta=(f,g,h,\varphi)$ in $(\mathcal{D},T)$ is said to be *distinguished* if $U\Delta$ is distinguished. On this case, $\Delta$ will be called an *essentially distinguished triangle*.

Note that every essential triangle that is isomorphic to an essentially distinguished triangle is distinguished. This is because $U$ is fully faithful.

Suppose $\Delta=(X\xrightarrow{f}Y\xrightarrow{g}Z\xrightarrow{h}TX)$ is a distinguished triangle in a pretriangulated category $(\mathcal{D},T)$ (again, $T$ is an autoequivalence). Since every equivalence can be promoted to an adjoint equivalence, we can take $\eta:1_\mathcal{D}\cong TT^{-1}$ and $\varepsilon:T^{-1}T\cong 1_\mathcal{D}$ satisfying the triangle equalities. Then $(T^{-1}Z
\xrightarrow{-\varepsilon_{X}\cdot T^{-1}h} X
\xrightarrow{f} Y
\xrightarrow{g} Z,\;\eta_{Z})$ is distinguished (as an essential triangle) iff $\Delta$ is.
In fact, more is true: $\Delta$ is distinguished iff for all $n\leq 0$ the following are essentially distinguished triangles:
\begin{align*}
(T^{n-1}Z
\xrightarrow{(-1)^{n+1}\varepsilon_{T^nX}\cdot T^{n-1}h} T^nX
\xrightarrow{(-1)^nT^nf} T^nY
\xrightarrow{(-1)^nT^ng} T^nZ&,\;\eta_{T^nZ})\\
\label{edt}\tag{2}
(T^{n-1}Y\xrightarrow{(-1)^{n+1}T^{n-1}g} T^{n-1}Z
\xrightarrow{(-1)^{n+1}\varepsilon_{T^nX}\cdot T^{n-1}h} T^nX
\xrightarrow{(-1)^nT^nf} T^nY&,\;\eta_{T^nY})\\
(T^{n-1}X
\xrightarrow{(-1)^{n+1}T^{n-1}f}T^{n-1}Y\xrightarrow{(-1)^{n+1}T^{n-1}g} T^{n-1}Z
\xrightarrow{(-1)^{n+1}\varepsilon_{T^nX}\cdot T^{n-1}h}T^nX&,\;\eta_{T^nX})
\end{align*}

This can be proved by induction (by rotating backwards one step at a time) from the following more general result:

> **Lemma 3.** Let $(\mathcal{D},T)$ be a pretriangulated category. Then $(B\xrightarrow{\beta}C\xrightarrow{\gamma}D\xrightarrow{\delta}E,\psi)$  is essentially distinguished iff $(A\xrightarrow{\alpha}B\xrightarrow{\beta}C\xrightarrow{\gamma}D,\varphi)$ is essentially distinguished whenever $\delta=-\psi^{-1}\cdot T\alpha\cdot\varphi$.

*Proof.* We have isomorphisms of essential triangles witnessed by the following commutative diagrams:
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
A@>>> B@>>> C@>>> D\\
@|@|@|@VV{\varphi}V\\
A@>{\smash{\alpha}}>> B@>>> C@>>> TA
\end{CD}
$$
and
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
 B@>>> C@>>> D@>{\delta}>> E\\
@|@|@VV{\varphi}V@VV{\psi}V\\
 B@>>> C@>>> TA@>{\smash{-T\alpha}}>> TB
\end{CD}
$$
(TR2) says that the codomain of the first isomorphism is distinguished if and only if the codomain of the second isomorphism is, so we are done. $\square$

What's important about essentially distinguished triangles is that they behave in all ways that matter like distinguished triangles. For instance, Lemma 3 is the essential counterpart to (TR2), and one can verify that the essential counterpart to (TR3) is also true. On the other hand, a [(co)homological functor](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0147) sends essentially distinguished triangles to exact sequences. Now suppose $\Delta=(X\to Y\to Z\to TX)$ is some triangle in some triangulated category. Then (TR2) says that $\Delta$ is distinguished if and only if some four consecutive terms in the sequence $X\to Y\to Z\to TX\to TY\to\cdots$ is distinguished. Consider now the long sequence:
$$
\label{lseq}\tag{3}
\cdots\to T^{-1}Z\to X\to Y\to Z\to TX\to\cdots
$$
any four consecutive terms to the right of $\Delta$ is a triangle, and any four consecutive terms to the left of $T^{-1}Z\to X\to Y\to Z$ is an essential triangle in a canonical way, as in \eqref{edt}. We can then equivalently state (TR2) by declaring that $\Delta$ is distinguished if and only if any four consecutive terms in \eqref{lseq} is distinguished.

*Remark 4.* Even though the idea of the previous paragraph sounds appealing, we are not doing anything fancy. One does not need to make up the theory of essential(ly distinguished) triangles to deduce that the long sequence $\cdots\to H_{n-1}(Z)\to H_n(X)\to H_n(Y)\to H_n(Z)\to H_{n+1}(X)\to\cdots$ coming from a d.t. and a homological functor $H:\mathcal{D}\to\mathcal{A}$ (where $H_n:=H\circ T^n$) is exact. This can be deduced from direct observation that $T^{-1}Z\to X\to Y\to Z$ is isomorphic to a distinguished triangle (if $X\to Y\to Z\to TX$ is distinguished). The main point of essential triangles is to have some rotation-free version of triangles to make sense of things that are not strict triangles.

---

**Addendum.** The following is highly conjectural and heuristic: Suppose we take the definition of a triangulated category and we make substitutions of the following syntagmas:
\begin{align*}
\text{triangle }&\rightsquigarrow \text{ essential triangle}\\
\text{distinguished triangle }&\rightsquigarrow \text{ essentially distinguished triangle}
\end{align*}
Then, if you adapt the axioms well you will end up with something that behaves like a triangulated category. For instance, TR2 should be now stated as the claim of Lemma 3. Let's call the gadget that arises from the resulting adapted definition an *essentially triangulated category*. One could give a notion of *essentially triangulated functor* between two of these and get a 2-category. Moreover, using $U$ from \eqref{indt} we could define a canonical 2-functor from the category of essentially triangulated categories to that of triangulated categories, and this would constitute an equivalence of 2-categories.